Can anyone tell me on why does the logic of colliding "if statement" not work if the variables to be checked are in a global scope Game.h?
so I just started chili's framework and tutorial, then i tried doing the code in my own way and it took me like 3 days until I figured out that for the "if statement" to work, I need to put it in a Local scope(Game.cpp) but I do not know why it doesn't work if it is in a Global scope(Game.h)
What I did before (Part Changed  before the current(fixed) version:
Game.h(Added)
const int   left_mobile = x_mobile - 5; const int   left_fixed = x_fixed - 5;
const int  right_mobile = x_mobile + 5; const int  right_fixed = x_fixed + 5;
const int    top_mobile = y_mobile - 5; const int    top_fixed = y_fixed - 5;
const int bottom_mobile = y_mobile + 5; const int bottom_fixed = y_fixed + 5;

bool colliding = false;

Game.cpp(Removed)
    //const int   left_mobile = x_mobile - 5; const int   left_fixed = x_fixed - 5;
    //const int  right_mobile = x_mobile + 5; const int  right_fixed = x_fixed + 5;
    //const int    top_mobile = y_mobile - 5;   const int    top_fixed = y_fixed - 5;
    //const int bottom_mobile = y_mobile + 5;   const int bottom_fixed = y_fixed + 5;

Whole Code (Game.h Previous version and the thing in question):
#pragma once

#include "Keyboard.h"
#include "Mouse.h"
#include "Graphics.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game( class MainWindow& wnd );
    Game( const Game& ) = delete;
    Game& operator=( const Game& ) = delete;
    void Go();
private:
    void ComposeFrame();
    void UpdateModel();
private:
    MainWindow& wnd;
    Graphics gfx;

    int x_mobile = 400;                       int x_fixed = 200;
    int y_mobile = 300;                       int y_fixed = 150;
    int r_mobile = 0;                         int r_fixed = 0;
    int g_mobile = 0;                         int g_fixed = 255;
    int b_mobile = 0;                         int b_fixed = 0;

//Part Added:
/*  const int   left_mobile = x_mobile - 5; const int   left_fixed = x_fixed - 5;
    const int  right_mobile = x_mobile + 5; const int  right_fixed = x_fixed + 5;
    const int    top_mobile = y_mobile - 5; const int    top_fixed = y_fixed - 5;
    const int bottom_mobile = y_mobile + 5; const int bottom_fixed = y_fixed + 5;*/

    bool colliding = false;
};

What I just did:
Game.h
#include "Keyboard.h"
#include "Mouse.h"
#include "Graphics.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game( class MainWindow& wnd );
    Game( const Game& ) = delete;
    Game& operator=( const Game& ) = delete;
    void Go();
private:
    void ComposeFrame();
    void UpdateModel();
private:
    MainWindow& wnd;
    Graphics gfx;

int x_mobile = 400;                       int x_fixed = 200;
int y_mobile = 300;                       int y_fixed = 150;
int r_mobile = 0;                         int r_fixed = 0;
int g_mobile = 0;                         int g_fixed = 255;
int b_mobile = 0;                         int b_fixed = 0;

bool colliding = false;

Game.cpp
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game( MainWindow& wnd )
    :
    wnd( wnd ),
    gfx( wnd )
{
}

void Game::Go()
{
    gfx.BeginFrame();   
    UpdateModel();
    ComposeFrame();
    gfx.EndFrame();
}

void Game::UpdateModel()
{
    const int   left_mobile = x_mobile - 5; const int   left_fixed = x_fixed - 5;
    const int  right_mobile = x_mobile + 5; const int  right_fixed = x_fixed + 5;
    const int    top_mobile = y_mobile - 5; const int    top_fixed = y_fixed - 5;
    const int bottom_mobile = y_mobile + 5; const int bottom_fixed = y_fixed + 5;

    if (
        right_mobile >= left_fixed &&
        left_mobile <= right_fixed &&
        bottom_mobile >= top_fixed &&
        top_mobile <= bottom_fixed
        ) {
        colliding = true;
    }
    else {
        colliding = false;
    }

    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_RIGHT))
    {
        x_mobile += 1;
    }

    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_LEFT))
    {
        x_mobile -= 1;
    }

    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_DOWN))
    {
        y_mobile += 1;
    }

    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_UP))
    {
        y_mobile -= 1;
    }

    if (x_mobile + 5 >= gfx.ScreenWidth) {
        x_mobile = gfx.ScreenWidth - 6;
    }
    if (x_mobile - 5 < 0) {
        x_mobile = 5;
    }
    if (y_mobile + 5 >= gfx.ScreenHeight) {
        y_mobile = gfx.ScreenHeight - 6;
    }
    if (y_mobile - 5 < 0) {
        y_mobile = 5;
    }
}

void Game::ComposeFrame()
{
    if (colliding) {
        r_mobile = 255;
        g_mobile = 0;
        b_mobile = 0;
    }
    else {
        r_mobile = 255;
        g_mobile = 255;
        b_mobile = 255;
    }
    {   
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_fixed, -5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_fixed, -4 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_fixed, -3 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel(-4 + x_fixed, -5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel(-3 + x_fixed, -5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_fixed,  5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_fixed,  4 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_fixed,  3 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel(-4 + x_fixed,  5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel(-3 + x_fixed,  5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_fixed, -5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_fixed, -4 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_fixed, -3 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel( 4 + x_fixed, -5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel( 3 + x_fixed, -5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_fixed,  5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_fixed,  4 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_fixed,  3 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel( 4 + x_fixed,  5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
        gfx.PutPixel( 3 + x_fixed,  5 + y_fixed, r_fixed, g_fixed, b_fixed);
    }

    {
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_mobile, -5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_mobile, -4 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_mobile, -3 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel(-4 + x_mobile, -5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel(-3 + x_mobile, -5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_mobile,  5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_mobile,  4 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel(-5 + x_mobile,  3 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel(-4 + x_mobile,  5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel(-3 + x_mobile,  5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_mobile, -5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_mobile, -4 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_mobile, -3 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel( 4 + x_mobile, -5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel( 3 + x_mobile, -5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_mobile,  5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_mobile,  4 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel( 5 + x_mobile,  3 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel( 4 + x_mobile,  5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
        gfx.PutPixel( 3 + x_mobile,  5 + y_mobile, r_mobile, g_mobile, b_mobile);
    }
}

As you can see here, I had to move the const int variables that stores the location of the of my x and y axis +- the location of the pixel.
so since this is collisions, I expected it to turn red whenever I put the moving object (square) into the non moving object(still square). Also this moving objectt is arrow key controlled. But since in chili's tutorial they said if theres no local variable it'll find the variable in the global scope so I thought it wouldn't matter if I put it in Game.h instead of Game.cpp, I just don't like it being so unorganised I like it when I separate the logic, the variables and etc. for readability purposes.
P.s
This may have ended up a bit disorganised cause I kept refreshing it from editing the question. I would like to fix it but I can't use tab to indent.
Edit:
This is the tutorial I was following:
link
In which in the tutorial he sometimes put the variables in Game.h but in the video some of the variables are in Game.cpp and not every variable is in Game.h so I tried putting all the variables in Game.h then I did trial and error on the code to figure out why the collision logic is not working I did it for 3 days until I decided to move the variables used in collision check from Game.h to Game.cpp in which it finally worked but my question is how and why? I thought the Game.cpp can get the value in game.h as it is included in the header file ( I tried putting the whole code but it kept saying add more comment)

Note the "minimal" in [mcve]

It's not clear what you're asking here.

An if statement must always appear within a function block (i.e. within scope of a function).    Variables can be defined at either "global" scope (outside any function) or within a function block - but must be declared (within whatever scope they are in) BEFORE there are used.   You can't, for example, use variables within an if statement, and declare the variables later in the source file.

I am not sure that i understand you
But you can move the variables to .cpp file instead of .h and write the class and it's method in .cpp as well
Note that .h are usually used to write a class and it's functions and not to put global variables in it.
And when you want to use .h you have to include it in .cpp file
#include<Game.h>


This seems more like a comment.
